# Important numerator and denominators in the evaluation of the integral: $\int_0^\infty x^t \operatorname{csch} x\text{ d}x$

Tags: integration, number-theory, zeta-functions

$$\int_0^\infty x^t\operatorname{csch}x\text{ d}x=\frac{a\zeta(t+1)}{b}$$
for $t\in\Bbb{N}$

How might one represent $a,b$ in terms of $t$?
(Note that $a,b\in \Bbb{N}$)

If possible, could one also provide a proof please?

Comment: Yea, I am aware of that.

Comment: use that $n^{-t-1} \Gamma(t+1) = \int_0^{\infty} x^t e^{-nx} dx$ so $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^t}{e^x-1} dx = \Gamma(t+1) \zeta(t+1)$, and please replace $csch(x)$ by $2/(e^x - e^{-x})$

Comment: Could you please write it as an answer? I have a hard time visualizing this.

Comment: $\frac{1}{e^x-1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-nx}$ so $\frac{2}{e^x-e^{-x}} = \ldots$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out with the use of user1952009's comments the solution:

$$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{2^t}{(2^{1+t}-1)t!}$$

Answer (score 0):

Using my newfound knowledge of Mellin Transforms, we can note that if we denote

$$F(s)=\int_0^\infty x^{s-1} \space f(x) \text{ d}x$$

Plugging in $f(x)=\text{csch} x$

One might note that $$\frac{a}{b}=F(s+1)$$

which is known as the result given.